# Vertical line not growing in C1reportDesigner(CrystalReport)

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report where In detail section I'm using vertical line that vertical line not growing even I set proeprty Anhcor="TopAndBottom" i tried also CanGrow & CanShrink=True but still its not working.I'm attaching screenshot & ReportDesign of it can any one please help.Thanks in Advanced

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the vertical line and click on Format Line.  Then check the box next to "Extend to bottom of section when printing".

This should ensure the line is always extended to the bottom of a section no matter how much it grows.  If you need to extend it through a section and into the following section, drag the bottom anchor through the first section or sections in the designer and drop it in the section where it should end.